# dnsmasq and network-manager internet share

Tags: networkmanager, dhcp, dnsmasq

I want share internet from my wi-fi card to another Ethernet adapter, but also I have full 'dnsmasq' installed, which I need also. As I understood it can lead to conflicts, so for now my setup even cant handle 'dhcp' for clients. I have errors from dnsmasq which complain on cant open socket. So any suggestions how to handle both?

Answer (score 0):

You can share the Internet between wireless and ethernet by simply creating a bridge over them.
Configure the dhcp server ignore the dhcp client running on bridge, then everything will work.

Comment: No. It's not option here. Want separated network with NAT and so on.